# Using PHP to extract the alt and/or title attributes from images

Tags: php, regex

I use this to extract the src of the image or the full path of image.

```
preg_match_all('/\< *[img][^\>]*src *= *[\"\']{0,1}([^\"\'\ >]*)/',$content,$matches);
```

It works for me so far, I get an array of all images sources. I am trying to be greedy and capture the alt and title values from the image tags.

I know it is not recommended to use regex to do it, but I really need a quick solution. I do not want it to return an error if alt or title is missing from the image tag.

Any input is appreciated and apologies. I know it is easier and appropriate with parser, but since I could get the src with that preg match i thought i could get the alt and title too! :)

Thanks a lot, happy new year :D

Comment: You're right, it *is* easier and more appropriate to do with a parser.  :) A regex to catch all possible combinations  is going to look awful.

Comment: Especially when you later decide you want to capture even more tags...

Comment: Ok the problem is that the script will be installed on many public servers for many users, and in case the parser does not exist or does not work on their host they will blame me :) Is there a parser which is compatible and supported by all servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution using PHP's DOM parser:

```
$domd = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$domd->loadHTML(file_get_contents("http://stackoverflow.com"));
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

$items = $domd->getElementsByTagName("img");
$data = array();

foreach($items as $item) {
  $data[] = array(
    "src" => $item->getAttribute("src"),
    "alt" => $item->getAttribute("alt"),
    "title" => $item->getAttribute("title"),
  );
}
```

Comment: question. The images are stored in a variable called $content.. can I use it instead of loading html or new document? How?

Comment: Third line: `$domd->loadHTML($content)`.

Comment: Wow :D It worked from the first attempt.. Okay thats simpler than regex. If some images do not have alt or title it won't stop the script i assume

Comment: Nope, you'll just have empty strings there.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, this is the best I could come up with in 3 minutes...

```
if(preg_match_all('@<img(\s?(src|alt|title)="([^"]+)"\s?)?(\s?(src|alt|title)="([^"]+)"\s?)?(\s?(src|alt|title)="([^"]+)"\s?)?\/?>@si',$content,$m)){
$img_array = array(
    $m[2][0]=>$m[3][0],
    $m[5][0]=>$m[6][0],
    $m[8][0]=>$m[9][0]
    );}

print_r($img_array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use phpQuery, it does this easily.

http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/ (the good link)

Comment: True, but the link is a bit off :)

Comment: Are there any straightforward examples for the lazy coder? lol.. basically I would like to get the src, alt, title in array so i can loop thru them and display my custom gallery..

Comment: i think you should be able to find examples on the site. i first used it amonth ago or smt, and I was very happy ;)